# Create Docker Image Python and Selenium on mac M2

Tags: python, docker, macos, selenium-webdriver

I need to create a docker container to upload to google cloud runner, so i can run a web scarper there using Selenium.
On my mac M2, i wrote in python the crawler, locally it works, but i am not managing to run the docker, even though i manage to build it.
the eror i get is, that he can't find google-chrome, even though i gave it in the required file.
i am sitting for hours to changing the version sof chrome and selenmium, but nothing helps.

Python code:

```js
def crawl_ag_grid(request):
    login_url = 'https://xxxxxx.com/login'  # Replace with the login URL
    target_url = 'https://xxxxx.com/dashboards/25'  # Replace with the target URL after login

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless') 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(login_url)

    # Perform login using Selenium
    email = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'email')
    password = driver.find_element( By.NAME,'password')
    email.send_keys('xxxxx@xx.com')
    password.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxx')
    login = driver.find_element(By.ID,'login-submit')
    login.submit()
```

my dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.8

# Install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx sudo -y



# Install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app
```

And my requirements.txt›› file:

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
selenium==4.11.2
chromedriver-binary==114.0.5735.90
google-cloud-bigquery==3.11.4
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
webdriver_manager==4.0.0
```

The error i get when running docker:

```
[2023-08-22 11:53:58 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
[2023-08-22 11:53:59 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process
```

Comment: Looks like you also need to install chrome in the Dockerfile, try something like this? https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @PaoloSini i tried that before, didn't help. Alos i have in the required file: chromedriver-binary==114.0.5735.90 and in the code i ask to install chrome:   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

Comment: Well these output lines `/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found` show that the google chrome browser is either not installed, or not on a `path` python is configured to use. I would try to install the right version of chrome in the Dockerfile, and make sure it can be run in the container by just typing `google-chrome` in the container's terminal.

Comment: @PaoloSini the issue i am not managing to install the correct chrome drivers in docker. Locally on my Mac it works, but when i try to build and run the docker it fails. My MacBook has the ARM chip, and there is no support for the chrome driver for it.